# How to remove gaps when borders overlap

Tags: css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B69OO.jpg)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#parent {
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#parent div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div id="parent">
        <div style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,1);border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);"></div>
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);"></div>
        <div style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,1);"></div>
        <div></div>
</div>
```

As shown, there are two overlapping border lines, one of which has a transparency of 0.2, which results in a gap in the overlapping portion of the border. I want to know how to eliminate the gaps that appear in overlapping parts

Comment: which color/'s of border you want to hide here ??

Comment: When borders overlap, only the border with transparency of 1 is displayed in the overlapped part, and the border with transparency of 0.2 is not displayed

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2e/8d/05/2e8d054bff60836a4a53627a1997d6ec.jpg

Comment: Maybe this picture can express what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly let me know if this is what you need?
if you want the border to be consistent then you need to apply `properties` for all `box`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 100% ;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#parent {
  margin:5px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#parent div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;     
}
#first{
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
}
#second, #fourth {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
 
}
#third{
   border-right: 1px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
}
```

```html
 <div id="parent">
        <div id="first" ></div>
        <div id="second"></div>
        <div id="third"></div>
        <div id="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE-1**

I am really not sure where is the `gap`, kindly check this below snippet I have removed outer border and increased the border to see clearly.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 100% ;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px solid red;
}
#parent div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;     
}
#first{
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
}
#second {
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
  
}
#third{
   border-right: 10px solid rgba(101,198,231,0.2);
 
}
```

```html
 <div id="parent">
        <div id="first" ></div>
        <div id="second"></div>
        <div id="third"></div>
        <div id="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just want to hide, when the two borders overlap, the border with transparency of 0.2 is hidden, only the overlapping part

Comment: Hide only the overlapping part

Comment: When you say hide, I am not getting it like those lines shouldn't meet at all?

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2e/8d/05/2e8d054bff60836a4a53627a1997d6ec.jpg             Maybe this picture can express what I mean.

Comment: @Lotus I was wondering what kind of requirement is this LOL.. I just updated new snippet kindly go through that, I don't see any gap between those border, I updated the size of the border to make sure you can see it clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry, I didn't let you understand what I mean. There are two different codes below. The result of the first code is not what I want, the result of the second code is what I want, but I implemented it through a pseudo-class. I want to know if there are other methods besides pseudo-classes to implement it.

Comment: Yeah I can see it clearly! thanks for spending time on this. If you get things working in Pseudo classes then why don't you use it? and also is it fine if I use it `table` behalf of `div`?

Comment: Yes, I should consider using <table>, I have solved my problem now, thanks

Comment: I am not sure I was of any help! cheers you were able to fix it!